# How to make Edge Chromium stop hiding 'http' in the Address Bar (Omnibox)?

Tags: windows-10, url, chromium, microsoft-edge

I've set all the following flags to **Disabled** in Edge Chromium 86.0.622.63 Stable channel:

```
edge://flags/#edge-omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme
edge://flags/#edge-omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-trivial-subdomains
edge://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-path-query-and-ref-on-interaction
```

However the browser still hides 'http' for me in the Address Bar (Omnibox). How do I stop it from doing this and make sure the complete URL is displayed *always*?

Comment: That article says nothing of substance